# For loop for creating (p5.js) Bodies

Tags: javascript, for-loop, p5.js, matter.js

I am making a game in p5.js and matter.js, for which I want to create a for loop to display one body (called BlueBox) from a class 7 times.
Here is what I have written so far:

```
const Engine = Matter.Engine;
const World = Matter.World;
const Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
const Constraint = Matter.Constraint;
var box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6, box7;
var bluebox1 = [];

function setup(){
    engine = Engine.create();
    world = engine.world;
    createCanvas(1400, 730);
    for(var i = 500; i <= 780; i = i + 80){
        new BlueBox(i, 460, 40, 80);
    }
}

function draw(){
    Engine.update(engine);
    background('#372C2B');


    for(var i = 0; i < bluebox1.length; i++){
        bluebox1[i].display();
    }
}
```

But the expected result [7 bodies lined up at y:460] is not appearing. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, in simple words?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the new objects to `bluebox1`:

<s>`new BlueBox(i, 460, 40, 80);`</s>

```js
bluebox1.push(new BlueBox(i, 460, 40, 80));
```